# Change shortcut for indicate Number of Cuts (Loop Cut Tool)

Tags: shortcut, modeling

Can't find a way to assign my custom shortcut to change Number of Cuts for Loop Cut Tool. Out of the box it is possible to change this number with the mouse wheel or with the Page Up and Page Down keys. But when using a graphics tablet and a pen, these combinations are terribly awkward. I want to appoint my own (Q and E) instead. How to do it?

P.S.: By the way, for most other operations that use the mouse wheel and PageUp/PageDown, I have already successfully remapped shortcuts (for example, for proportional editing). But for the number of cuts, there is no such option in the Preferences (or I did not find it).

Comment: Is it at all possible for you to enter a numerical value? (I'm aware it's a tablet)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett
Thanks for your comment. Yes, I can enter a numerical value, but it's still not as convenient as I would like. All I want is to be able to reassign shortcuts. But it looks like this particular shortcut is hardcoded in Blender.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure then. I tried a bunch of things, with no success. It doesn't mean it's impossible, but there's no way that I'm aware of.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett
Okay, thanks for helping.